# Django: want to improve speed of query

Tags: python, mysql, django, view

I have a django app which displays the list of items for each client. it displays an item id, an alternative id, title and more other information. Because I have a lot of I items (Each client could have thousand of items), it can take very long to load up all of the items. Is there a way to improve this speed?

```
def client_items(request, client_id = 0):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('items.html', {'items':items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

{% for item in items %}
        <tr class="items_table_row">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{item.pk}}" value="{{item.pk}}" checked="checked"></td>
                <td>{{item.company_id}}</td><td>{{item.alternative_id}}</td><td>{{item.title}}</td><td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.format}}</td>
                <td><span id="{{item.pk}}" name="type">{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}</span></td><td>{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest.date.date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you really want to display HTML with thousands of items?

Comment: well that is how our clients want it. Of course I won't mind Pagination'

Comment: Please define "very long".  Please include some time which is acceptably short.  Also, please profile this snippet to find out where the time is being spent.   Since you've written so little code, your code **can't** be at fault.  You need to measure database, network, server, and client times that are leading to this "very long" (whatever that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Pagination"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/)

Answer (score 0):

[**Paginate results**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) into something more manageable than thousands of item. Without pagination it not only slow, but also gives bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the items are loaded with a constant number of database queries. For most views, you should be able to load all your data with only one database read.

If you notice that the queries are increasing or decreasing depending on how many items you display, you will probably need to include a select_related() in your queryset.